# How do I use if statements with the HTML5 date picker?

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding a project start and project end date picker, `<input type="date">`, to a quote page for my web clients, however, I have never worked with these before. How can I use the data from these date pickers to create an if statement that if the project end date is earlier than the end date or vice versa, it will display an error message?

Comment: 1) Learn how an `if` statement works. 2) Learn how to get the date value from the picker 3) Learn how to compare two dates.

Comment: David, check codepen for checking dates  - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/AXxqmP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what you want. Add ids to your date pickers, get their value using simple selectors and add them to the variables. Compare the variables in the if function

```
var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate_id').value
var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate_id').value

if(startDate > endDate){display error}
else{do nothing}
```